# php capitalize second letter in sentence min 10 characters long

Tags: capitalize

Hello I have a project where I need to cApitalize only the second letter in a sentence. I now that PHP has strtoupper()  and string strtoupper ( string $string ) ucfirst() returns first letter

So here is my best attempt

```
<?php

$str = "capitalize";

$str = ucfirst(strtolower($str)); // makes all the letters lower case 
?>
```

This is where I get confused if 0 = the first letter and 1= 2nd  then could I just make an `array(")` or `count_chars()` then `$val`

Comment: You can take an individual letter from the string using e.g. `$str[1]` for the second letter, capitalise it, then place it back in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Its a old question, just came across this so would put an answer based on @doppelgreener comment.

This should work :

```
$str = "capitalize";
$str[1]= strtoupper($str[1]);
echo $str; // cApitalize
```

Answer (score 0):

i have one idea to perform this operation..
example

```
$strmain='capitalize';
$result = substr($strmain, 0, 1); //result is c
$result1=str_replace($result,'',$strmain);//now your result1 is apitalize
$result2=ucfirst($result1); //now result2 is Apitalize

$finalresult=$result.$result2 ///now your finalresult is cApitalize
```