# How to make the second character uppercase?

Tags: php, substring, offset, uppercase

I work with Apple Product Name a lot

```
"iphone"
"ipad"
"imac"
```

What would be the quickest way to make the second character uppercase?

```
"iPhone"
"iPad"
"iMac"
```

---

## I tried

```
// $name = iphone
if ($name[0] == 'i') {
    strtoupper($name[1]);
    dd($name); //iphone
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php capitalize second letter in sentence min 10 characters long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829362/php-capitalize-second-letter-in-sentence-min-10-characters-long)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to replace the value in original variable:

```
$name[1] = strtoupper($name[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Perfect answer

```
 $word ='iphone';
 $result = str_replace(substr($word,1,1),ucfirst(substr($word,1,1)),$word);
 echo $result;
```

Comment: This doesn't explain what you changed or how it works.